# How do I reinstall WD Smartware on my Mac?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I reinstalled my OS but forgot to backup WD Smartware. Is there a way to reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

Down load from [western Digital site](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?level1=1&lang=en)